# conditional expectation of the positive part of y

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I'm stuck with the following problem...

> Assume that $ \mathbb{E}( y \vert x) = a + bx, $ where $a$ and $b$ are
>   parameters. Define $ z :=\max(0, y)$. What are you able to conclude
>   about the relationship between $ \mathbb{E}( y \vert x)$ and
>   $\mathbb{E}( z \vert x)$ ?

I tried the following:

> Attempt1: Decompose the positive and negative parts of y
>
> $ y:= y^{+} - y^{-}$, where $ y^{+}=z, y^{-}=-\min(0, y)$  are positive
>   and negative parts of y, respectively.
>
> $\mathbb{E}( y \vert x) = \mathbb{E}( y^{+} \vert x) - \mathbb{E}(
>  y^{-} \vert x)$
>
> $ = \mathbb{E}( z \vert x) + \mathbb{E}( -y^{-} \vert x)$
>
> $ = \mathbb{E}( z \vert x) + \mathbb{E}[ min(0, y) \vert x]$

For the 1st attempt, I tried to find distribution of $\min(0, y)$ with cdf(distribution fcn technique) but no assumption is given in the problem, so I failed....

> Attempt2: Use CEF-Decomp property (Conditional Expectation Function)
>
> According to Angrist-Pischke, MHE Thm 3.11,
>
> > $ Y = \mathbb{E}[ Y \vert X ] + \epsilon$, where $ \mathbb{E}[\epsilon \vert X] = 0$
>
> $ \mathbb{E}( y \vert x) = a + bx \Rightarrow y = a + bx + \epsilon$
>   $ \mathbb{E}( z \vert x) =  \mathbb{E}( z \vert x, y \geq 0)P(y \geq 0) + \mathbb{E}( z \vert x, y < 0)P(y < 0) $
>   $ = (a+bx)P(y \geq 0) $
>
> since $\mathbb{E}( z \vert x, y < 0) = 0$

For the 2nd attempt, I failed to find a probability that Y is greater than or equal to zero... Someone told me that this problem is related to order statistics or median... Please help! Thanks in advance!!